Vue2 not recognizing property in data section
I'm having trouble understanding why the property uploadedFiles is not recognized in this Vue2 component. When running in a browser I get the following error:
[Vue warn]: Property or method "uploadedFiles" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Minimal component:
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="filter in ['test 1', 'test 2']" :key="filter">
      <h3>{{ filter }}</h3>
      <div v-if="uploadedFiles[filter]">Present!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
  
<script>
export default {
  name: 'UploadFilter',
  data: function() { 
    return { 
      uploadedFiles: {} 
    }
  }
};

Found:
The <script> block was not closed with </script>

Please, provide a way to reproduce. It's currently not reproducible. This could happen if the component failed to be normally initialized

Removed last dependency. How can I check if the component failed to be normally initialized?

There should be other errors or warnings in the console

Unfortunately nothing above this error. The error below is [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'test1')". This is logical if uploadedFiles is apparently undefined

As said, you need a way to reproduce to solve this. Could be something that you didn't show, probably specific to your project. E.g. there's no  in the code you posted. It looks like a typo but could produce the problem you have

And.. you solved my problem. I did somehow forget to put the  closing tag in the file and now it works correctly.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The <script> block must be closed with </script>. If you forget that Vue2 will not account for that codes existence.

Just remove this post please, no one is going to have the same typo as you.

@Wimanicesir I respectfully disagree. Typo questions are commonly closed, but this fix is a useful one. It's not a coincidence I suggested it as a potential cause. Unclosed script tag is a known problem with vue compiler that results in no error.

That happens even in plain HTML. No error and not executing any JS code within. IMO this has nothing to do with Vue. So even you have experience with this mistake and happen to work in Vue, that this is automatically a common problem.
